# Build additional CSS file in angular build

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-builder, angular-devkit

### Background

[`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) allows us to customize the webpack config of angular build, [tutorial here](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21). I am using it to build the additional scripts for web extension (Chrome/Firefox).

Here is the `extra.webpack.config.js` that I have included in `angular.json`

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');

const scriptsDir = __dirname;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "background-script": resolve(scriptsDir, 'background-script/boot.ts'),
    "fill-manager": [resolve(scriptsDir, 'fill-manager/boot.ts')],
    "site-bridge": resolve(scriptsDir, 'site-bridge/boot.ts')
  }
};
```

As expected it outputs `background-script.js`, `fill-manager.js` and `site-bridge.js` alongside angular build artifacts. As this webpack config is merged with the angular's webpack config, we can control all the optimizations, hashing, source maps etc from a single `angular.json` file.

### Problem

I also want to bundle additional css files that would be used with extension scripts and be controlled by angular build.

I might be able to add specific rules, loaders etc to `extra.webpack.config.js` but I do not want to deal with postcss, autoprefixer and sass loaders etc as its already being done inside angular.

Just like script files, simply adding css entry inside `extra.webpack.config.js` does not produce css file i.e.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    ...
    "fill-manager": [resolve(scriptsDir, 'fill-manager/boot.ts'), resolve(scriptsDir, 'fill-manager/main.css')],
    ...
  }
};
```

Is there a way where I can specify a css/scss file entry in `extra.webpack.config.js` and it just output a bundled css file using configuration based on angular?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to that? I'm currently having the exact same issue and there isn't a lot of usefull information online...